# Compute derivative of a composed function leaving indicated some derivatives

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Is there a way to define in Mathematica a generic differentiable function $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in such a way that when it computes the derivatives of a composed function involving $g$ it leaves indicated the derivatives of $g$ instead of actually computing them?

I'll explain myself better with an example:

Suppose we have defined this "generic" $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and we have defined $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $F(x)=7Log[x]$. 
When given the command $D(F(g(x,y)),x)$ I would like to have the output $7\partial_x(g)/g$. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not only possible, it is actually quite straightforward. Define `f` in the usual way:

```
f[x_] := 7 Log[x]
```

Then take the derivative of the composition with `g[x,y]` (being an "undefined" generic function). The answer is as you expect:

```
D[f[g[x, y]], x]
```

[image]

So there is no need to specially define the function g[x,y].